Can I use AWS SES as an invoke to my lambda function without owning a domain?
I want to use AWS SES service to set inbound rule , to invoke my lambda function when receiving a new Gmail message. I don't want it to pass any records to lambda function , I just want it to invoke the function.I don't own domain , I want to use SES service purely for personal reasons.Is there any way to invoke my lambda function when receiving a Gmail without owning a domain? If not , what other free/cheap options/ways do I have?
I tried using SES service without domain (just verified email) which clearly isn't enough , since my account is still in sandbox mode and I can't find rule sets for Email Receiving. I also tried zappier , it's Gmail-to-webhook ability is what would do for me , but I don't want to pay for it since I 1.am broke student 2.will just use it for this one little lambda-selenium project. Rest of the platforms ask for the verified domain as well.Wish gmail itself had some kind of service with similar functionality.
